# How to install Ubuntu on IBM Power 710?

Tags: powerpc

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 in IBM Power Server 710 but I don't know how to.
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) question says "Try it out", but the regular 64 bit ISO for amd64 won't work here, and I don't know how to "try it" in PowerPC.

I am looking for an answer containing step by step instructions of how to install Ubuntu Desktop in a ppc64el system (or Ubuntu Server, if a desktop version is not available for this architecture).

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) does not address PowerPC.

Comment: What architecture are you using?  Only `ppc64el` is supported; the old `ppc` is no longer supported by Ubuntu.   In my experience though; most errors are the faulty write of ISO to media; so did you verify your ISO as being perfect? and write to media as *flawless* assuming you are using the correct ISO for your hardware to begin with.

Comment: @guiverc According to [this](https://www.topgun-tech.com/products/ibm-power-systems/power-710/) link, the processor supports 8 GB to 256 GB memory, so it is most likely `ppc64el`.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it's my understanding their is a *live* installer used for the `ppc64el` release too; so I can't see why *try* isn't available (though I have **no** experience with that architecture myself & the `subiquity` ISO isn't quite the same as a desktop)  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-ppc64el

Comment: One ISO QA testcase set (there are 4 for *ppc64el*) can be found here for *focal* (the *daily* now refers to 20.04.4) - http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds/238461/testcases; a quick overview though I'd look in the server docs like I my prior comment for end-user intended docs.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [IBM Tech sheet](https://www.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_sm/4/877/ENUS8231-_h04/index.html), the IBM Power 710 Express Server uses POWER7+ CPU's.

However, according to both [Debian docs](https://wiki.debian.org/ppc64el) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ppc64) (I'm sure there are other reputable sources as well), the `ppc64le` architecture is only supported on POWER8 CPU's and later.

This means that Ubuntu (and also Debian) is only supported on systems with at least POWER8 CPU's.